# How to Get the value from function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, json.net

Does someone know how can I return the value from a function that contains `$.getJSON`?
The issue is I'm trying to call that function from other function in order to get the value, but it's returned as `undefined` all the time!
How can I make it work?

```js
function TranslateLatLanToAddress(LatLng) {
  var latlng = "34.1574183,-118.437125";
  var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=false";
  $ = jQuery;
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
      var address = data.results[i].formatted_address;
      // var address = data.results[i].address_components[4].long_name + data.results[i].address_components[6].short_name;
      // alert(address);
      return false;
    }
  });
}

function GetVal() {
  var retVal =TranslateLatLanToAddress(LatLng);
  alert(retVal); // It's undefined!!!
}
```

Comment: The `A` in `ajax` means ASYNCHRONOUS -- which means that ajax calls are non-blocking; they work in the background as they pass control to the next line. That is considered AJAX 101. Therefore, by the time you're checking for the value returned, the ajax request is not complete.

Comment: what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You really do not have many choices; whatever you have to do that depends on the result of the ajax request, do it within the ajax callback. Or you could also ready up on jQuery promise or deferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX calls are asynchronous. This means that while the request is being sent to the server (Google Maps) your script will continue.

This is a **good thing** because it means your page will continue to load while waiting for the result.

To use this to your advantage, you can use `callback` methods.

```
function TranslateLatLanToAddress(LatLng, fnCallback) {
    var latlng = "34.1574183,-118.437125";
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=false";
    $ = jQuery;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {                                // getJSON is asynchronous
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var address = data.results[i].formatted_address;        // get the result
            fnCallback(address);                                    // execute the callback from the parameters
        }
    });
}


function GetVal() {
    TranslateLatLanToAddress(LatLng, function(address){             // note the new callback that takes an address as a parameter
        alert(address);                                             // the callback is fired from within the SUCCESS method and now address has a value
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asyncronous, what you're doing is (pseudo):

```
[call TranslateLatLanToAddress]
    |
    + ----which triggers an ajax call---[ AJAX response ]
    + ----Get here the AJAX response?          |
                                               +--- Now is available!
```

So what you can to do is to call a function in the AJAX get callback:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  // Other code here....
  alert( "AJAX DONE" ); // Or like: //  myCallbackFunction( data );
});
```

passing the desired AJAX response data (if needed) to your `myCallbackFunction( data );` , in any case your fn `myCallbackFunction` will be called only after AJAX finishes it's work.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is using XMLHTTPRequest, so it's naturally an async function. It's best to assign a callback function is to execute something.

```
function TranslateLatLanToAddress(LatLng) {
  var latlng = "34.1574183,-118.437125";
            var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=false";
            $ = jQuery;
            $.getJSON( url, execute)
              .done(function() {
                console.log( "second success" );
              })
              .fail(function() {
                console.log( "error" );
              })
              .always(function() {
                console.log( "complete" );
              });
}

function execute(data) {
       for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
          console.log(data.results[i].formatted_address);
       }
}
```

Also $.getJSON have another convenience callback (done, fail, always) you can override with some function like success callback.